# Extend Blade Template from Database stored string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

My problem is that I need to pass string as an argument to view, which contains the Blade Template tags to be rendered. I've done my research and I believe the other problems asked don't relate to mine. Hence following is what I want to achieve.

I want to retrieve the *master layout* from *database* and *extend* the *child views* from it. So in my case, the view that is to be passed to *view()* method needs to be extended from a string in database.

So something like the following should work in page.blade.php

```
@extends("<html>@yield('content')</html>") ---> the string shall be passed from database.
@section('content')
...
...
@endsection
```

Or some other code from the *Controller* itself may be okay, such as I call for the main layout first, then pass it the child view, which replaces the *'content'* section.

Answer (score 1):

Well, considering the over-whelming response from the community even after many views, I decided to go for a work-around, until I find a better solution. (Sarcasm intended)

Documenting it here, so as to give a clue to those who might be trying the same.

1. **Extend the child view from a master view** (say *db_master.blade.php*)
2. In your Controller, **put contents from the database column into the *master view*** (*db_master.blade.php*) using either *FileSystem* class or *file_put_contents* (whatever you feel more secure with).
3. Now **return the child view** as usual.

**Note**: Make sure you pass secure code to the master view (that is, take care of giving users access to blade templating engine, as they can inject actual php code)

---

Please help with feedback and suggestions.

Comment: Although this is an old post, but I had a similar use case which I posted my own solution on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489775/save-blade-templates-to-database-rather-than-file/50075222#50075222) in StackOverflow. In case it helps anyone who comes across this post. Like I did in moshing up different ideas I read on Stack to build the solution that worked for me.