# Save blade templates to database rather than file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to save my `blade` templates to database, because the `header and footer` of each page `is customizable` for the user. I want to let my users create the layout themselves and then for each request from a given user, I want to serve the page, using the layout specified by that user.

The necessary variables that are passed by the controller are provided to them in the documentation.

Note: I trust my users. They are all stake-holders of the project and are programmers, so server side code execution is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is an old post but just in case someone stumbles across it like I did. I achieved similar while using the Laravel Framework, by saving the view in database such that, whenever I need to display the view, I retrieve it from DB, and load it into a file using the `file_put_contents()` php function and render it with the `view()` method. For example;

```
$blade = DB::table('pages')->where('name', 'index')->first();
file_put_contents('template.blade.php', $blade->view);

//Note if I also need to pass data to the view I can also pass it like so
//$data = ['page_title' => 'Testing Blade Compilation using views Saved in DB'];
// return view(template, $data);

return view('template');
```

While again in my own case for added security, I created base templates with the blade templating scheme & injected user created inputs into the template after sanitizing the generated input using [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) and rendering the view. For example

```
$view = view('base.template')->render();
//similarly like the above I can load any data into the view like so
//$data = ['page_title' => 'Testing Blade Compilation using views Saved in DB'];
//$view = view('base.template', $data)->render();

$purifier = new HTMLPurifier(HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault());
$with_purified_input = $purifier->purify($user_generated_input);
str_replace('view_variable', $with_purified_input, $view);

return $view;
```

Answer (score 1):

I realised that I can improve security and caching if I just let them insert the static content only. The only thing I need to change is the main content, so I can just let them set a `token` where the content is to be placed. As is in the above answer by @huzaib-shafi , I did the following...

```
//In controller
$content = View::make('final',compact('data'));
$token = "<meta name='_token' content='" . csrf_token() ."'";
$scripts = View::make('final_scripts',compact('data'));

$view = str_replace_first("<%content%>", $content, $templateInDatabase);
$view = str_replace_first("<%token%>", $token, $view);
$view = str_replace_first("<%scripts%>", $scripts, $view);

return $view;
```

This enforces them to use `bootstrap` in their template, because I use `bootstrap styles` in my `blade` templates, but it is acceptable in my case.

Comment: But the string replacements are overhead as well. But I don't know any better solution either.

Answer (score 0):

I asked and answered a similar question some days ago. So far as I know, Blade doesn't process view content from database columns. Although you can use compileString() method of View. But you should have a look at the following questions.

[Extend Blade Template from Database stored string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38251605/extend-blade-template-from-database-stored-string)

[Let users create custom blade layouts / store in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38398783/let-users-create-custom-blade-layouts-store-in-database)

Comment: Should I go and save the template on every request and then process from it? @huzaib-shafi

Comment: I would definitely discourage that due to resource usage it involves. I think you should go for the `token` concept

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 9 you can use blade Facades to render from DB:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
 
return Blade::render('Your Blade Content {{ $parameter1}}', ['parameter1' => 'Name']);
```